# In a diamond pattern of Observables, what does `withLatestFrom` guarantee?

Tags: rxjs5

The documentation for the Observable operator `withLatestFrom` in RxJS 5 seems unclear on exactly how interdependent observables (i.e. a diamond pattern of observables) behave.

My question is very similar to [Rxjs - Subscribing to interdependent observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318193/rxjs-subscribing-to-interdependent-observables). A short description follows:

I have three observables A, X and Y. They are configured such that:

- X depends on A.
- Y depends on A and X via the `withLatestFrom` method.

In code, this looks like:

```
let a$ = Rx.Observable.interval(...)

let x$ = a$.map(...)

let y$ = a$.withLatestFrom(x$).subscribe((a, x) => {
    console.log("a = " + a)
    console.log("x = " + x)
})
```

My question is, if I were to subscribe to `y$`, would I be guaranteed to have the latest value of `x$`?

It is my understanding from the question linked above that this is a hard guarantee: Whenever there is an event on `a$`, `x$` will be evaluated first, and then `y$` will be evaluated using the new value of `x$`. However, I feel the RxJS documentation is unclear on this matter.

Does `withLatestFrom` do what I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the default (immediate) scheduler, it works just as you would expect:

```js
const a$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)

const x$ = a$.map(x => x + 1)

const sub = a$.withLatestFrom(x$).take(3).subscribe(([a, x]) => {
  console.log("a = " + a)
  console.log("x = " + x)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.2/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

However, if `x$` is on a different scheduler, you run into "strange" behavior (notice how it takes 2 seconds for the first value to appear, 0 is skipped).

EDIT: Interestingly enough, rxjs "forgives" the small discrepancy and combines the correct values from `a = 2` onward (but I wouldn't rely on that effect)

```js
const a$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)

const x$ = a$.map(x => x + 1).delay(1)

const sub = a$.withLatestFrom(x$).take(3).subscribe(([a, x]) => {
  console.log("a = " + a)
  console.log("x = " + x)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.2/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```